# No adapter attached; skipping layout - beginner issue

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-volley

Im using volley to download the JSON data from a server, setting the Adapter within the function that reads and parses the data. However, the adapter is not being recognized. The problem is, I have successfully implemented the adapter in another activity with the same method without errors. The following is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras!=null) {
        user_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("user_id");
    } else {
        Intent logIn = new Intent(JoinedActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(logIn);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_joined);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(this));
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    GetJoinedEvents();
}

public void GetJoinedEvents(){

    String tag_string_req = "req_getJoinedEvents";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Config.URL_USER_lIST_EVENTS+user_id, new Response.Listener<String>(){
        @Override

        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // progressDialog.dismiss();
            Log.i("responseTest",response);

            try {

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
                int length = result.length();

                HashMap<String, String> events;
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    String event_id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_EVENT_ID);
                    String name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_EVENT_NAME);
                    String date = jo.getString(Config.TAG_EVENT_START_DT);
                    String weekday = jo.getString(Config.TAG_EVENT_WEEKDAY);
                    String event_type = jo.getString(Config.TAG_EVENT_TYPE);

                    events = new HashMap<>();
                    events.put(Config.TAG_EVENT_ID, event_id);
                    events.put(Config.TAG_EVENT_NAME, name);
                    events.put(Config.TAG_EVENT_START_DT, date);
                    events.put(Config.TAG_EVENT_WEEKDAY, weekday);
                    events.put(Config.TAG_EVENT_TYPE, event_type);
                    eventList.add(events);
                }

                listAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(JoinedActivity.this,eventList, user_id);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Error", "Bad internet connection");

        }
    }) {};
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest, tag_string_req);
    Log.i("URL", stringRequest.toString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to this is just to initialize the Recycler view and adapter on the onCreate. Then later on when you have the data you could create a swapItems method just for the purpose of changing the data within the recyclerview through the adapter, but in a way that both the RecyclerView and its adapter is instantiated as the activity starts.

on your swapItems you could do something like below:

```
public void swapItems(List<Events> eventList) {
    if (eventList != null) {
        this.items = eventList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();// should call this to let the recyclerview know that our data set has changed
    }
}
```

Then you could just call it via the activity by

```
listAdapter.swapItems(eventList);// this is done the moment you already got your list of events
```